# How to select a color anywhere on the screen using a semi transparent selector?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, drawing, gdi+

**Small disclaimer:** This is my first time messing with Graphics in Forms, therefore I am not so familiar with the concepts here

Alright, so I have been trying to make an application that tracks the cursor's position in the entire screen and draws an Ellipse around it. The code I borrowed was from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31610878/draw-a-circle-around-cursor-c) question (I changed the X and Y position of the Ellipse in order to auto-adjust itself around the cursor regardless of its size) everything works perfectly up to this point. Here is the code so far:

```
        public static float width;
        public static float height;

        public Main(float w, float h)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
            width = w;
            height = h;
            BackColor = Color.White;
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
            TopMost = true;
            TransparencyKey = BackColor;
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick;
        }

        Timer timer1 = new Timer() { Interval = 1, Enabled = true };

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            DrawTest(e.Graphics);
            base.OnPaint(e);
        }

        private void DrawTest(Graphics g)
        {
            var p = PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
            g.DrawEllipse(Pens.DeepSkyBlue, p.X - (width / 2), p.Y - (height / 2), width, height);
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Invalidate();
        }
```

So now I want the application to check whether a preassigned color is present within the area of the Ellipse, and if so, get the position of the nearest pixel to the cursor that has this color. I have searched everywhere and haven't found any method of doing it.

I get that the logic behind it would be to get all the pixels within the Ellipse, check if the color exists and find the one pixel with this color nearest to the cursor but I haven't been able to implement it.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simplified method (it doesn't require PInvoking, mouse tracking/hooking or other *low level* operations).
It can work well enough if you don't need too much control on what happens behind your Window, you don't want to record animated Images, just do what's in the question's description: capture colors of external Windows / Desktop elements currently under the mouse pointer.

A trick is used here: the Form's `BackColor` and its `TransparencyKey` are set to a blue-ish color (`Color.Navy`). This allows to have a transparent but *solid* Form.
In practice, `MouseMove` events are raised even if the Form is completely transparent an can be *clicked-though*.

Another quasi-trick, is to double-buffer the Form, using the standard [DoubleBuffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.doublebuffered) property, not the `OptimizedDoubleBuffer` which can be enabled calling the `SetStyle()` method.

The [ResizeRedraw](http://ResizeRedraw) property is set to true, so the Form redraws itself if/when resized.

With this setup, to get the Color under the Cursor position, you just have to take an one-Pixel snapshot of the current Screen, using a Bitmap sized as `(1, 1)` (we need just that one Pixel) and use the (not very fast but functional) [`GetPixel()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel) method to read the Color from the Bitmap.

When the Mouse right button is clicked, the Color under the Cursor is saved in a `List<Color>` (which is accessible using the public/read-only `SavedColors` property) and then drawn in a PictureBox used as canvas for this *Palette*.

To build this example:

- Create a new Form
- Add a PictureBox (here, named **`picColor`**) and anchor it Top-Right. This Control is used to show the current Color under the Cursor when the Mouse pointer moves.
- Add a second PictureBox (here, named **`picPalette`**) under the previous one and anchor it Top-Right-Bottom. This is used to draw the current palette of saved colors.
  In the Designer, use the Events Panel to subscribe to the Paint event using the handler method you can find in this code (i.e., don't add another).

---

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class frmColorPicker : Form
{
    Color m_CurrentColor = Color.Empty;
    List<Color> m_SavedColors = new List<Color>();

    public frmColorPicker()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ResizeRedraw = true;
        DoubleBuffered = true;

        TopMost = true;
        BackColor = Color.Navy;
        TransparencyKey = Color.Navy;
    }

    public Color CursorEllipseColor { get; set; } = Color.Orange;

    public List<Color> SavedColors => m_SavedColors;

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        GetColorUnderCursor();
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        var rect = GetCursorEllipse();
        using (var pen = new Pen(CursorEllipseColor, 2)) {
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, rect);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) {
            m_SavedColors.Add(m_CurrentColor);
            picPalette.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseMove(e);
        Invalidate();
    }

    private Rectangle GetCursorEllipse()
    {
        var cursorEllipse = new Rectangle(PointToClient(Cursor.Position), Cursor.Size);
        cursorEllipse.Offset(-cursorEllipse.Width / 2, -cursorEllipse.Height / 2);
        return cursorEllipse;
    }

    private void GetColorUnderCursor()
    {
        using (var bmp = new Bitmap(1, 1))
        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {
            g.CopyFromScreen(Cursor.Position, Point.Empty, new Size(1, 1));
            m_CurrentColor = bmp.GetPixel(0, 0);
            picColor.BackColor = m_CurrentColor;
        }
    }

    private void picPalette_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        int rectsCount = 0;
        int rectsLines = 0;
        int rectsPerLine = picPalette.Width / 20;

        foreach (var color in m_SavedColors) {
            using (var brush = new SolidBrush(color)) {
                var rect = new Rectangle(new Point(rectsCount * 20, rectsLines * 20), new Size(20, 20));
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, rect);
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.DarkGray, rect);
                rectsCount += 1;
                if (rectsCount == rectsPerLine) {
                    rectsCount = 0;
                    rectsLines += 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

This is how it works:

[image: Transparent Form GetPixel]