# Is it possible to render a form component outside the form UI? C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ocr

I am working on an application that **retrieves a text block** from a **selected region** on **any image** using a **sizeable rectangle**. It works perfectly on the Form UI but I wanted to know if there is a way to **programmatically render it on the screen outside the form**. It sounds silly, but if it can be done it would be better to just extract text from the screen than loading an image every time onto the form.

[image: The component to render outside form]

Comment: What you can do is create a transparent, border-less form, which covers the entire desktop, and which then acts as parent for your rectangle control. I've done this in the past, but that was a long time ago, and I don't have the details for doing it handy.

Comment: Try [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62433353/7444103), posted the other day. You can use your control on that Form.

Comment: You can actually set the Desktop as the parent of a Control (`SetParent([Control].Handle, IntPtr.Zero)`), with transparency, too, but it can get weird :)